# Python Interpreter: Can't assign to literal

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, variable-assignment

I wrote a program with this code in it:

`('<') = raw_input(v1), ('>') = raw_input(v2)`

and recieve the message `syntax error: can't assign to literal`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you *want* to do? because your code doesn't make sense

Comment: What you're doing wrong is assigning to a literal, like the error message says. Is that not specific enough? Do you know what a literal is? Do you know what assignment is?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm new to m\python, and no, i don't know what a lieral is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29 . You can't assign to `('<')` because that simplifies to `'<'` which is a string, not a variable. Trying to do this is like trying to change the value of 4.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel But when I type it without singe quotes, it gives me a `syntax error`.

Comment: Again, what are you trying to do? When you assign something, you assign to a variable. `<` is not a legal variable name.

Comment: You're going to want to start at the beginning.  If the answers here don't make sense, ask for clarification and we'll do the best we can.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're attempting to assign something the user enters to an instance of a String.  That doesn't work.

To grab your question in a comment on another answer and attempt to incorporate it, if you want to be able to type `v1` and have it return `'<'`, you need to do this:

```
v1 = '<'
```

It sounds like, before you go much further, you *strongly* need to work through some of the basic programming concepts like assignment, variables, and functions.

Answer (score 2):

To take a stab at what you *mean*:

```
user_provided_value = raw_input("Say something:")

if user_provided_value == "v1":
    print "Heavier than a duck!"
elif user_provided_value == "v2":
    print "Lighter than a duck!"
else:
    print "You must enter either v1 or v2"
```

What you are *saying* is (ignoring the `v1` and `v2` variables):

```
('<')              #1 Set '<'
                   #2 [ ('<') is the same as simply saying '<' ]
 =                 #3 to be the result of assigning
                   #5 to a tuple composed of
 raw_input()       #6 what the user types in at the prompt
 ,                 #7 (the comma operator creates a tuple)
 ('>')             #8 And '>'
 =                 # to be 
 raw_input()       #4 what the user types in at the prompt
```

Typing those lines out in legible English, you are saying:

"Set `'<'` to be the result of assigning a user-defined value from `raw_input()` to the tuple `raw_input(), '>'`".

Saying, "Set some fixed value to be equal to the user-provided value" is the algebraic equivalent of saying "Set 5 to be equal to the value of the previous equation."

---

`*` Since the comma operator is one of the least binding operators, you are actually setting the **tuple** composed of the strings `raw_input(), '>'` to be equal to the string from the second `raw_input` call.

The statement can be broken down as follows:

> Set the string '<' to be the value resulting from evaluating the statement raw_input(), '>' = raw_input()

`raw_input(), '>' = raw_input()` is interpreted as:

> Set the tuple composed of the results of calling raw_input() and '>' to be equal to the results of calling raw_input()

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get input with `<` and `>` as the prompts? If so, this is what you should be doing:

```
v1 = raw_input('<')
v2 = raw_input('>')
```

`raw_input` takes in the prompt as a parameter, and the output of this function call (what you type in the terminal) gets assigned into `v1` and `v2`.

Another option in one line, since it looks like you are trying to do one line:

```
v1, v2 = raw_input('<'), raw_input('>')
```

The reason you are getting that error message is `('<')` is what is called a literal. A literal is a value that is explicitly typed out in your code. Basically, not a variable. This is like saying `3 = len(mylist)`... How do you assign the output of the `len` function to 3? You can't, because 3 is not a variable. You should only be assigning into a variable, in python (and most other languages) typically some sort of word-like set of characters, like `v1` or `myinput`:

```
v1 = len(mylist)
```

Comment: would that allow me to type `v1` and it would show `<` ?

Comment: It will show what you typed in for input via the command line interface. If you want to store the string '<' into v1, you just do v1 = '<'. You should likely elaborate your question to what you are trying to do to get better hel